# Calling subprocess.call() on a .exe in another directory

Tags: python, subprocess, graphviz

I have some .dot files I want to convert to pdf with python. The command goes like this:

```
dot -Tpdf -o output.pdf input.dot
```

This command works if I execute it straight from cmd. But using Pythons *subprocess.call* it does not work.

The dot.exe is in a separate directory with dependency on other files, I've tried running it like this:

```
subprocess.call(['C:/graphviz-2.38/release/bin/', 'dot', '-Tpdf', '-o ' + file + '.pdf' + file])
```

And like this ('dot' added to path)

```
subprocess.call(['C:/graphviz-2.38/release/bin/dot', '-Tpdf', '-o' + file + '.pdf' + file])
```

The latter just runs dot.exe and doesn't take any arguments, the former gives me the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xmltodot2.py", line 22, in <module>
    subprocess.call(['C:/graphviz-2.38/release/bin/', 'dot', '-Tpdf', '-o ' + file + '.pdf' + file])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 172, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 394, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 644, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied
```

How can I run dot.exe that has dependencies on files in its directory from another directory?

I'm new to Python and unsure of the syntax.

Thanks!

EDIT:

Full code

```
import os, fnmatch, subprocess, string
from subprocess import call

# opens the directory
listOfFiles = os.listdir('.')
# file extensions to look for
pattern = "*.xml"
pattern2 = "*.dot"
path = "C:/graphviz-2.38/release/bin"

#Converts every dot-file in the directory to pdf
for file in listOfFiles:
if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, pattern2):
    os.chdir(path)
    subprocess.call(['C:/graphviz-2.38/release/bin/dot', '-Tpdf', '-o' +         
file + '.pdf', file])
    print("Converted " + file + " to pdf")
```

Comment: I'm a bit worried about the part `'-o' + file + '.pdf' + file` in `['C:/graphviz-2.38/release/bin/dot', '-Tpdf', '-o' + file + '.pdf' + file]` shouldn't this be: `['C:/graphviz-2.38/release/bin/dot', '-Tpdf', '-o' + file + '.pdf',  file]` (note the comma instead of the plus before the last file, so that the file is an argument and not added to the pdf part)

Comment: You're right, changed it and I'm now getting a diffrent error. Error: postprocessor_delete_HVAPerson_Person_4364333776528879544.dot: syntax error in line 1 near '"'
Converted postprocessor_delete_HVAPerson_Person_4364333776528879544.dot to pdf
Error: subgraph_delete_HVAPerson_Person_4364333776528879544.dot: syntax error in line 1 near 'subgraph'
Converted subgraph_delete_HVAPerson_Person_4364333776528879544.dot to pdf

Comment: Might be something in the input file, do you still have access to the `.dot` file so you can inspect it?

Comment: I do, I've tried running the command from cmd on the .dot file and it successfully converts it to pdf so I think the .dot file is intact.

Comment: What is the value of `file` as you append for the output `.pdf` but for the input you do nothing.

Comment: It is the name of my .dot testfile "postprocessor_delete_HVAPerson_Person_4364333776528879544" . I do not append it for the input because when i print "file" it says "postprocessor_delete_HVAPerson_Person_4364333776528879544.dot", it includes the file extension.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean that the output file would be `postprocessor_delete_HVAPerson_Person_4364333776528879544.dot.pdf`

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try to change the working directory from within your script to control execution context. This is like `cd` in your command line reproduction. `os.chdir` is a standard library method to change cwd.
2. Ensure your script is running with sufficient permissions.

Comment: I added the path to the dot.exe directory in os.chdir(), it's switching to the directory as intended but now it can't find the .dot files I'm testing on which are located where my python script is. edit: How do I ensure it is running with sufficient permissions?

Comment: Re: permissions I would start by verifying installation with PATH options enabled. The process itself should be viewable in your favorite process manager. Re: dotfile if you need to call from the new location after `chdir` then do you have the option of also copying the target over to that dir?